# NotificationCenter not always calls observer when specified object is a String

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I have been trying to check why my observer is sometimes called and sometimes isn't when specifying a `String` `object` to filter out notifications.

My original code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(update), name: .pathContentsChanged, object: self.folder.path) // Where path is something like "/user/folder"

@objc func update()
{
    // Not always called
}
```

My current workaround, which confirms that the notification `object` does match `self.folder.path`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pathContentsChanged(_:)), name: .pathContentsChanged, object: nil) // No object specified anymore

@objc func pathContentsChanged(_ notification: Notification)
{
    // This does get called every time
    guard let path = notification.object as? String,
        path == self.folder.path else
    {
        return
    }
    self.update() // notification.object and self.folder.path do match
}
```

Is it inherent at how `String`s work on Swift? Is it because `notification.object` could be a bridged `NSString`?

Comment: Is your issue that the original observer wasn't passing the object? By that I mean to say there's a big difference between a selector of `update` versus `pathContentsChanged(_:)`. In your second code snippet, what if you *did* pass an object? Or more importantly, in your first bit of code what if you changed the function signature to include the notification?

Answer (score 1):

`NotificationCenter` filters notification *per-object* comparing objects by-reference, and not by `isEqual` as you'd might expect. So posting notification with different strings (even equal by content) might not result your observer to be filtered out.

In general, String is not that object to be used in `notification.object` (due to its nature, constants, bridged, etc.)... Most usual scenario is to have some your custom object (that owns workflow) to be the originator of notification (so be notification object).

And if you want to have strings in object then yes, your observers have to be non filtered 'object: nil' and act conditionally inside handler.